# Deprecation of offline_access - handling non-human access

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions

I've been scouring the net for ages with this one, and I'm not sure if there is a solution at all, but thought I'd post and see if there's a response... thanks in advance!

Several of our customers (who we build websites for) have their Facebook feeds brought into their website (and their Twitter feeds).  Before the removal of the offline_access permission, this was no problem. We'd set our app up, authenticate the account, get the access token and then we could bring in the live feed into their websites forever.  However, now with the new system, there doesn't seem to be a way of doing this without human intervention.

Essentially, we have these websites bringing in the feeds from the relevant Facebook accounts, with the long access_token (60 day token).  However, when this limit is reached, there is no "user" to re-authenticate the app, as its just the server that makes these requests.  Is it a case of having to set reminders for all these accounts, and then every two months we (as the web agency) have to log in to all the accounts and get new access tokens to provide to the scripts so they can carry on working? Or is there an alternative which I am just not seeing?

Thanks again!

Neil.

Comment: Yes, the best solution I can see is to send a reminder for page admins to login and get a "fresh" `access_token` before expiry by 2 or 3 days

Answer (score 0):

There is no alternative that I know of. Once the token expires after 60 days, the user must re-authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

No alternative way, user must login to provide you the new access token

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/